# CSS to target class within attribute

Tags: css

I have a navigation item in a div, I just want to target this one with an attribute value, But my CSS does not work so far. Code so far below is:

I am trying to target the `navDepts` class

**HTML**

```
 <div class="primary-nav" data-name="about">
        <div class="subNav">
                <ul class="navDepts">
                    <!-- <li></li>-->
                </ul>
        </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.primary-nav [data-name="about"] .subNav ul .navDepts {
  display: none!important;
}
```

Comment: _.primary-nav[data-name="about"] .subNav ul.navDepts_  you have extra space, remove it

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing `ul` from your CSS. Because `ul` and `.navDepts` are on the same level.

```
.primary-nav[data-name="about"] .subNav .navDepts {
  display: none!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS inheritance is not proper:

```css
.primary-nav[data-name="about"] .subNav ul.navDepts {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="primary-nav" data-name="about">
        <div class="subNav">
                <ul class="navDepts">
                    <!-- <li></li>-->sadsadsad
                </ul>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found two mistakes in your code.

- First one is that there should not be any space between attribute selector and related `class`.
- Second, I presume that you mean to select `ul` with `.navDepts` class. So I removed the space between them.

So here is the corrected css:

```css
.primary-nav[data-name="about"] .subNav ul.navDepts {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.primary-nav[data-name="about"] .subNav ul.navDepts li{
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="primary-nav" data-name="about">
  <div class="subNav">
    <ul class="navDepts">
      <li>list item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS . May it will help you out.

```
   .primary-nav [data-name="about"] >.subNav ul.navDepts {
        display: none;
    }
```